# void(0) returns `undefined`, but allows property access. Why?

Tags: javascript

So `void` returns `undefined` after executing the expression passed to it.  `undefined` throws exceptions when you try to access its properties.  So why is that `void(0).prop` returns `undefined` instead of crashing?

```
alert("void(0) => " + void(0)); // undefined

// How is it that this doesn't throw an exception?
alert("void(0).someprop => " + void(0).someprop); // undefined

// Exception, can't access property of undefined.
alert("undefined.someprop => " + undefined.someprop); // crash
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bFhLS/

Comment: Even weirder - `void(0).someprop.test` => error

Comment: @Doorknob That is not weird, that is expected.

Comment: Made a fiddle that logs instead of alerts, personal preference: http://jsfiddle.net/bFhLS/1/

Comment: @epascarello Why not? Apparently there are two types of undefined.... *gets enlightened after reading answer*

Comment: The last one is the same as `( void 0 ).someprop` which throws an error. That is why when you use void and `typeof` you should no use `()` since it

Comment: Or a reason why you should use `()` but you should wrap them around the operator and argument: `(typeof x)` and `(void 0)`. That should remove all ambiguity.

Comment: Javascript, as a language, looks every day more like a joke. The runtime environment is really good, but the language itself is close to inexcusable.

Comment: @6502, When you understand what is going on here it makes perfect sense. People using an operator like a function is the issue here, not the language itself. It is like saying basic math is horrible because you also do not like operator precedence there.

Comment: @epascarello: `void` operator is just totally useless (if you really need what it does just write `(..whatever.., undefined)` instead). An explanation doesn't give it a meaning. Even `[1]==1` being true has an explanation, but it's not a good idea because of that.

Comment: Its "usefulness" is in situations like `return foo() || void bar() || baz()` ...where you want to have the side effect of `bar()` while guaranteeing a falsey result allowing `baz()` to evaluate. Though there are better ways to write this IMO.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`void` operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.2) doesn't use parenthesis itself. So, the statement is probably being parsed as:

```
void( (0).someprop )
```

And accessing `someprop` from the `Number`. Rather than as:

```
(void (0)).someprop
```

As you were probably expecting, which does throw an error.

Comment: So why would `void(0).toString();` be `undefined` instead of `"0"`?

Comment: @Matias No, because it's parsed as `void((0).toString())`

Comment: [js operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for future reference

Comment: You can see it more clearly if you use something other than zero, like: `var foo = { go: function() { console.log("going"); } }; void(foo).go();` - this calls the `go` function on the `foo` object.

Comment: Well that's a pretty devious interpreter quirk, but that exactly seems to be the case. Thanks @JonathanLonowski

Comment: world would be a better place if people stopped using parentheses to make operators look like function calls. another one is `typeof()` arggg

Comment: @soulcheck: Completely agree.

Answer (score 1):

`void` is an **operator**, it is **NOT** a function.

`void(0)` is equivalent to `"void 0"`.

So `void(0).someprop` is equivalent to `void 0..someprop`.

To prove,

```
void(undefined).someprop
```

throws an error, since it will be evaluated as (`someprop` doesn't exist in `undefined` for sure)

```
void undefined.someprop
```

Comment: It may confuse some that the `void 0.someprop` equivalent actually will throw an error, but in that case, the error is for a different reason.

Comment: Should probably be `0..someprop` to as the (1st) `.` is part of the number literal.